# How to use Bootstrap3 media queries for custom CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am developing a responsive website. I am using twitter bootstrap 3. I need to reduce the padding , margin, font size for mobile. So, how can I use the bootstrap 3 media query in custom CSS? I have used following code but it is not working

```
@media (min-width: @screen-sm) and (max-width: @screen-sm-max){
    #promo .col-xs-12{padding-bottom:72px;}
}
```

Comment: Refer to their documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use pixel values, not just `-sm` or `-sm-max` instead enter your value where the breakpoint happen.